# Send a jsp response along with status code in Spring REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

I want to send a jsp error page along with the HTTP status code. I tried the below code but it is showing just the string and not the index.jsp page:

```
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity handleException(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e)
{

    return new ResponseEntity("index.jsp",HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

}
```

Can someone please explain how this can be done?

EDIT: I tried the modelandview approach but instead of 404 as the status code it is displaying 200 OK status code.

Comment: I have updated edit 1 section ... Have u tried that...

Comment: Yes I tried that..but still the status is 200 Ok. It seems status is one of the properties of modelandview here and not the usual "STATUS".. I have to extract it from the response since it is not available independently.

Answer (score 1):

`ResponseEntity` will always return an `Object`. In your case `String`.

```
ResponseEntity("index.jsp",HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

To load specific jsp page you can use `ModelAndView`.
You can also pass additiona info to ModelView which can be handy.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());  //  Can read this in JSP by getting url
    mav.setViewName("index"); // calls index.jsp
    return mav;
}
```

**Edit 1:**

```
mav.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```

Comment: How do I send the status code alongwith the jsp page?

Comment: I tried the above code. I am getting the jsp page but the status code is 200 instead of 404.